# vim - Store a backup before each write

Tags: vim, vimrc

I want to create a backup of the file I'm editing before each write. For example, if I am editing some `file.txt`, when I go to write the file with `:w`, I want vim to first save a backup of `file.txt` within a directory (i.e. `~/.vim_backups/`) as `file_2013-01-01_01-01-01.txt`, where this represents `YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS.txt`. I am aware of alternatives such as version control, but I'm curious if this is possible in vim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This vim wikia article titled: [Keep incremental backups of edited files](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_incremental_backups_of_edited_files), sounds like what you're looking for. There's this method which attaches a save routine so that it's mapped to the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

> With the following mapping:
>
> ```
>    fun! InitBex()
>      let myvar = strftime("(%y%m%d)[%Hh%M]")
>      let myvar = "set backupext=_". myvar
>      execute myvar
>      echo myvar
>     endfun
>     map <Esc> :call InitBex()<CR>
> ```
>
> You can easily refresh the backupextension time everytime you hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. So you can get backups every minute, every hour, every day and so on.

There are several other methods discussed in the Wiki topic.